# Deploy a token which you can only send in multiples of x

Tags: tokens

Im a beginner in solidity. Is there a way to deploy an ERC20 token that can only be sent in multiples of X or else the tx fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simply add that restriction in functions `transfer` and `transferFrom`.

For example, suppose you want to restrict it to multiples of 100:

```
contract MyERC20Token {
    ...

    function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
        require(value % 100 == 0);
        ...
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
        require(value % 100 == 0);
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```